How to make 2 objects to collide each other?
Description
I am trying to make 2 objects to collide each other. The collision I am trying to make detects weather the 2 objects are touching / intersecting each other by first calculating their Box3(boundingBox) and then using the .intersectsBox() function to return a boolean value.
Using a physics engine didn't do any good because I am using DragControls and DragControls do not update the position of the RigidBody. I am expecting something like this:
Example of Collision
Code
Here, obj1 is the first object and is a BoxGeometry and obj2 is the second object and is also a BoxGeometry. When obj1 intersects obj2 the .intersectsBox() return true as the boolean value.
const obj1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
const obj2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,5,2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());

const obj1Box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj1);
const obj2Box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj2);

box1.intersectsBox(obj2);

What I tried
I tried a storing the previous position of obj1 and when it intersects obj2 I check the current  position and then set the position of the obj1 to the non-colliding previous position. I was unable to make this logic work.
What I require
If someone already has a codesandbox regarding this, please do help me out using that, also if possible an answer in react-three would would save me a loads of time, but vanilla three.js will also work.
Current Code
import * as THREE from "three";
import { DragControls } from "three/addons/controls/DragControls.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let renderer, scene, camera, dragcontrols, controls;
let objects, boxMesh1, boxMesh2;

function init() {
  const bgColor = 0x263238;
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(bgColor, 1);
  renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x263238, 20, 60);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  );
  camera.far = 100;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  camera.position.set(1, 1, -5);

  controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  boxMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
  );
  scene.add(boxMesh1);
  
  boxMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 5, 2),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
  );
  boxMesh2.position.set(2,2,0);
  scene.add(boxMesh2);

  dragcontrols = new DragControls([boxMesh1], camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  let lastSafePosition = boxMesh1.position.clone();
  
  dragcontrols.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
    controls.enabled = false;
    lastSafePosition.copy(event.object.position);
  });
  
  dragcontrols.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    controls.enabled = true;
    console.log(controls.enabled);
  });
  
  dragcontrols.addEventListener('drag', () => {  
    boxMesh1.position.y = 0;
  const box1Mesh = event.object; // The mesh being dragged
  const box1BoundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(box1Mesh);
  const box2BoundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(boxMesh2);

  if (box1BoundingBox.intersectsBox(box2BoundingBox)) {
    box1Mesh.position.copy(lastSafePosition);
  } else {
    lastSafePosition.copy(box1Mesh.position);
  }
  })
  const metreSize = 10.0;
  const metreDivisions = 40.0;
  const decimetreSize = 10.0;
  const decimetreDivisions = 400.0;

  const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(
    metreSize,
    metreDivisions,
    0x8fc8df,
    0x8fc8df
  );
  scene.add(gridHelper);

  const gridHelper2 = new THREE.GridHelper(
    decimetreSize,
    decimetreDivisions,
    0xd7eef5,
    0xd7eef5
  );
  scene.add(gridHelper2);
  
  gridHelper.position.set(0,-0.5,0)
  gridHelper2.position.set(0,-0.5,0)
  
}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();


And why would this not work because of the control scheme you chose? The controls don't care about your objects really. Are you updating the bounding boxes often enough?

@somethinghere I tried to make it work but I it only collides with the wall once and then gives an error which I don't know how to resolve, I am new and dont know how to perform complex stuff like this.

Can you share the error you are getting as well? It's easier to debug the thing if we can see what is going wrong? If you could turn this into a very simple snioppet with two boxes and the collision code that errors out it would help a lot with helping you.

Sure, please provide me some time so that I can recreate it, cause I have removed the code

@somethinghere I have modified the question and also added the code snippet that I was using, if you can help me regarding this I'll be very thankful

Could you still tell us what error you are getting in the console? From just a glance it seems like you shouldn't get any errors in the event listener but the actual error message you got seems pretty useful to figure out where things are breaking and help you solve this.

So I got it working, the error was a missing event parameter, but still the colliding is snappy, is there a way I can make it smoother

Answer
Thanks for the time, efforts and reply @somethinghere
So I figured it out myself and if anyone is stuck and wants to find how to make 2 objects collide smoothly without snapping effect here's the complete working code:
import * as THREE from "three";
import { DragControls } from "three/addons/controls/DragControls.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let renderer, scene, camera, dragcontrols, controls;
let objects, boxMesh1, boxMesh2;

function init() {
  const bgColor = 0x263238;
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(bgColor, 1);
  renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x263238, 20, 60);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  );
  camera.far = 100;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  camera.position.set(1, 1, -5);

  controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  boxMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
  );
  scene.add(boxMesh1);
  
  boxMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 5, 2),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
  );
  boxMesh2.position.set(2,2,0);
  scene.add(boxMesh2);

  dragcontrols = new DragControls([boxMesh1], camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  let lastSafePosition = boxMesh1.position.clone();
  
  dragcontrols.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
    controls.enabled = false;
    lastSafePosition.copy(event.object.position);
  });
  
  dragcontrols.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    controls.enabled = true;
    console.log(controls.enabled);
  });
  
  dragcontrols.addEventListener('drag', (event) => {  
  boxMesh1.position.y = 0;
  const box1Mesh = event.object; // The mesh being dragged
  const box1BoundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(box1Mesh);
  const box2BoundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(boxMesh2);

  if (box1BoundingBox.intersectsBox(box2BoundingBox)) {
    const collisionNormal = new THREE.Vector3();
    const overlap = new THREE.Vector3();
    overlap.x = Math.min(box1BoundingBox.max.x - box2BoundingBox.min.x, box2BoundingBox.max.x - box1BoundingBox.min.x);
    overlap.z = Math.min(box1BoundingBox.max.z - box2BoundingBox.min.z, box2BoundingBox.max.z - box1BoundingBox.min.z);

    if (overlap.x < overlap.z) {
      collisionNormal.setX(box1Mesh.position.x > boxMesh2.position.x ? overlap.x : -overlap.x);
    } else {
      collisionNormal.setZ(box1Mesh.position.z > boxMesh2.position.z ? overlap.z : -overlap.z);
    }
    box1Mesh.position.add(collisionNormal);
    lastSafePosition.copy(box1Mesh.position);
  } else {
    lastSafePosition.copy(box1Mesh.position);
  }
  })
  const metreSize = 10.0;
  const metreDivisions = 40.0;
  const decimetreSize = 10.0;
  const decimetreDivisions = 400.0;

  const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(
    metreSize,
    metreDivisions,
    0x8fc8df,
    0x8fc8df
  );
  scene.add(gridHelper);

  const gridHelper2 = new THREE.GridHelper(
    decimetreSize,
    decimetreDivisions,
    0xd7eef5,
    0xd7eef5
  );
  scene.add(gridHelper2);
  
  gridHelper.position.set(0,-0.5,0)
  gridHelper2.position.set(0,-0.5,0)
  
}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();


If someone is a beginner and still needs a better representation:
Glitch Link
The glitch link contains the whole source code and also interactive version of it.
